# Unit Testing with Model::Find Fails in Laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am creating unit tests for my rather large Laravel application.

This test passes all assertions. It creates a new database entry for the advertising status model.

```
/** @test **/
public function create_a_new_advertising_status_test()
{
    $status = AdvertisingStatus::create(['name' => 'Test']);
    $this->assertNotNull($status);
    $this->assertCount(1, AdvertisingStatus::all());
    $this->assertEquals($status->name, $this->advertisingStatus['name']);
}
```

This test fails the NotNull assertion as it says $status is null, which means that the Find method is failing.

```
/** @test **/
public function edit_an_existing_advertising_status_entry()
{
    $status = AdvertisingStatus::create(['name' => 'Test']);
    // $status = AdvertisingStatus::first(); // This successfully finds the database entry
    $status = AdvertisingStatus::find(1); // This fails to find the database entry
    $status->name = 'Edit';
    $status->save();

    $this->assertNotNull($status);
    $this->assertCount(1, AdvertisingStatus::all());
    $this->assertEquals($status->name, "Edit");
}
```

It appears like the find function and subsequently the where function takes too long to locate the entry, so the test renders the $status variable null.

Aside from using the `Model::first()` function, does anyone have any idea how to overcome this?

I'm wondering if it's because my application is extremely large and takes a long time to run because I'm using `RefreshDatabase`

Comment: first() and find(1) are not exactly the same. first is the lowest id, find(1) is id = 1. Try dd(AdvertisingStatus::first()) and see what the id is!

Comment: @KurtFriars it is 1. It's refreshing the database every time it runs a test, so there are no entries. I also checked with var_dump and it shows the id of 1.

Comment: Really weird then. Hope you find a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a factory first, then you will use it like this:

```
   $status = factory(AdvertisingStatus::class)->create(['name' => 'Test']);
```

Comment: I don't see how the factory would make it work considering it just returns a model with populated fields. Nevertheless, I'll give it a go

Comment: I Update my answer :)

Comment: the create method returns the object so there is no need to save it. When I change the object's name, it must be saved, hence the saving of it. The issue is with the find method, not the order of my logic because the first() method returns the correct object. I believe it has something to do with it taking a long time to find the object

Comment: Take a look on your db. On Laravel 7, I noticed that most of the time with refreshDB the first entry has ID of 2, not 1. 

To see, if you can access your db via Tinker or SequelPro, you can remove the RefreshDatabase trait, and check which ID is generated in the table. If there is no status with ID = 1, here you go.

Comment: The create method is a wrapper for $model = new Model(); $model->save() but it appears like the factory and some reshuffling has worked.. cheers!

Comment: great. So if factory has worked, please Mark as Solved

Comment: I have thanks. I also removed the other code field you had because it was not relevant.

Comment: yes, definitively. I confused `Create()` with `firstOrNew()`